# Como implementar um serviço de autenticação em uma projeto SOA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, token, microsserviços, soa

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando SOA aonde tenho uma aplicação web feita em Angular 2 e vários micro serviços em Spring Boot, entre os serviços existem os serviços de autenticação e de notificação que poderiam ser compartilhado entre outras aplicações.
Sobre implementar o serviço de autenticação tenho as seguintes duvidas:

- Qual é o melhor método de autenticação para este cenário ? como ele funciona?
- Usando a autenticação via token seria recomendado verificar o token com o serviço de autenticação nas requisições feitas para outros serviços? (por exemplo cria rum filtro em outros serviços em que para cada requisição é extraído o token do cabeçalho, então o mesmo é enviado para o serviço de autenticação e caso esteja correto é retornado as informações do usuário, senão o status 401 )?
- Informações dos usuários devem ser persistidas no serviço de autenticação?

Answer (score 1):

Como você está trabalhando com Angular utilizando o padrão de SPA (Single Page Application) sua sistema conversa HTTP diretamente com o servidor.

Hoje o protocolo mais utilizado para este cenário é o OAuth 2.0. O Auth 2.0 se concentra na simplicidade do desenvolvedor de clientes ao mesmo tempo em que fornece fluxos de autorização específicos para aplicativos da Web, aplicativos de desktop, telefones celulares e dispositivos.

Para maiores informações sobre OAuth 2.0:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Quanto a sua pergunta o OAuth 2.0 para execução das APIs faz a validação de Token. Porém, este serviço de validação está no servidor de OAuth e pode ser executado por qualquer aplicação. O Ideal para este cenário é que você tenha um gateway de APIs na frente fazendo este papel de proxying e segurança (aplicando as políticas do OAuth). Como você está usando Spring Boot o projeto Zuul do Spring Cloud funciona como um gateway de APIs.

Quanto ao servidor de OAuth você pode ter o próprio de servidor de recurso OAuth utilizando dependências do próprio Spring:

http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

Caso seja possível terceirizar a autenticação você pode usar os provedores de recurso OAuth do Facebook ou Google como muitas aplicações web / mobile fazem isso hoje atualmente.

Caso for criar o seu os métodos do padrão OAuth devem ser implementados e para isto deverão acessar informações do cliente para autenticação / autorização. Portanto, a informação de cliente deverá estar persistida de alguma forma. Como o OAuth acessa esta informação depende da estrutura que existe dentro da sua arquitetura atual.

Comment: Existe alguma representação gráfica ou diagrama de sequencia deste método ? Dessa maneira todas requisições para outros servidores seriam forçados a validar  o token com o servidor de autenticação ?

Comment: A definição do fluxo de autorização vem do próprio protocolo OAuth 2.0. Seguem um link interessante que tem o diagrame de passos: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2